# Intermittent 502 bad gateway error(using nginx,nodejs,mongodb)

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

We are using nodejs(v 0.10.29 ) ,express,nginx( version 1.4.6) with mongodb(v 2.6.3) replicaset and getting intermittent 502 bad gateway error. pm2 logs is unable to log error though nginx aerror.log is showing

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from     upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: somedomain.com, request: "GET /img/abc.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/img/abc.png", host: "domain.com", referrer: "http://domain.com/admin/"
```

and access.log is saying:

```
"GET /url/abc.html HTTP/1.1" 502 723 "http://domain.com/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
```

can anyone guide me with the issue?

Comment: Have you tried w/o using pm2? How often does this happen, have you got more information?

Answer (score 14):

It probably isn't a problem with nginx per se but more of a problem with nodejs. The 502 bad gateway error means that nginx asked the nodejs server for some information, and the nodejs server answered and then "promptly hung up the phone." The "hung up the phone" is more of a reference to the "Connection reset by peer" part of the message.

Now, this could be indicative of many different problems, so I can't give you a definitive answer.

It could be that there was an actual error in processing the request, which would require tracing the bug through the js code.

It could be a memory issue (what does your memory usage look like)?

Or it could be a timeout error on node's part, either because it took too long to return an answer or because the code was buggy or because the system ran out of memory.

I know that I used to get intermittent timeout errors between nginx and php-fpm because nginx would give up waiting for php. I adjusted the memory usage and the timeout settings to fix that (and I optimized the php code).

If you can provide more specific information about memory / load usage or logs from node or the application or even a general pattern in the 502 errors (is it localized to a geographic region, a browser, an OS?), then the answer could be less speculative.

Comment: This is a good answer! Is there any way to debug issues like this better? I've noticed that nginx logs are pretty non-descriptive and don't really point to a clear problem.

Comment: @Jordan What do you mean by "debug issues like this better"? The problem is somewhere in the node code, so you have to trace through the code to see where it is failing. Off the top of my head, I'm not familiar with packages that can help with the tracing. You can always do the tedious and annoying but reliable method of putting in extra log statements through the code to find out where the process stops. If it's a memory thing, then you can look at the memory usage and see if it caps out. You can try increasing wait times for nginx and see if that makes things work.

Comment: I had a similar problem but in ASP.NET Core - I wasn't allocating enough memory to my docker image and it was running out of memory so the request was dying, and nginx was reporting 502. Thanks!

Comment: Putting some alerts like using cloud-watch may also help to find , this way problem can be detected if for example it occurred at the same time when cloudwatch graph shows high memory or CPU

Answer (score 2):

In our case nginx was on top of Node.js, which was automatically started by Forever. Due to an error in Redis database contents the Node server crashed intermittently and nginx returned either a 502 or 503 error. It took us some time to find the reason, as Node's crashing messages were logged only by Forever.

So, no failure on nginx or its configurations, the Node server (and its background services) were the source.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me on server to server connection. [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) server was shooting at the [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) a package of 300-400 bullets like:

```
get http://example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

The second couldn't respond to this on time and gave up saying `502`.

The solution I came to was sending request one-by-one on in smaller chunks.